# Meterial React Table Bulk Update - Selected rows needs to be edited but I'm getting all the rows in editable mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add one feature in Material React table that is Bulk update so for that I have added one button "**Bulk Update**" by default it is disabled but when we select rows from checkboxes in table then it gets enabled.

```
const [tableMode, setTableMode] = useState('row');

{tableMode === "row" ?
    <Button disabled={ !table.getIsSomeRowsSelected() && !table.getIsAllRowsSelected()}
    onClick={e => { hadleBulkUpdate(table) }}
    startIcon={<EditIcon />}
    variant="contained">
    Bulk Update   
    </Button>
    :
    <Button
       disabled={!table.getIsSomeRowsSelected() && !table.getIsAllRowsSelected()}  
        onClick={e => { BulkSaveEdit(table) }}
        startIcon={<FolderSpecialIcon />}       
        variant="contained">
       Save Bulk Update                                    
    </Button>
}

const hadleBulkUpdate = (table) => {                
    if(table.getSelectedRowModel().rows.length > 10) {
        setDbOpLabelUpdate("Cannot update more than 10 rows.");
        setMessageType("warning");
        return false;
    } else {
        if (tableMode === 'row') {
            setTableMode('table')
            setRefreshCancel(true);
        } else {
            setTableMode('row');
            setRefreshCancel(false);
        }            
    }     
}~~~


There is a check that user cannot select more than 10 rows. So, when I select rows like 5 or 6 then click on Bulk Update button then all rows are getting in a editable mode.

I want only those rows editable which I have selected, like if I select 5 rows then only 5 rows needs to be in editable mode.

But currently it is not happening. Please help on this.
```

Comment: Can anyone help on this question, I'm still looking for solution.